# What does 'rat' mean here? How does this makes sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"The rat fights the tigress underwater and kills her but takes pity on the cubs and tends them lovingly - I don't know how to do the scene," the producer would say and Subbu would come out with four ways of the rat pouring affection on its victim's offspring.

..........................................................................

In the above sentence what does rat means? Does it mean "a rodent" or "a disgusting person"?

By the text, it looks like rat means "a rodent" i.e the animal Rat.

But what I don't understand here is that how does this scene makes sense?
How is a rat being portrayed to fight a tigress, and that to be underwater?

The above scene is supposed to be of an Indian movie in the industrial times, when normal movies were shot with primitive technologies and ideas.
So, how does this scene makes sense? Is it really what it is  said in the lines? or there is something else that these lines want to portray?

Thanks to all the wonderful people on this website, helping me like their own child :)

[image: Original Parahgraph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the word 'rat' refers to the 'rodent'.
This could be a clue. After describing the scene, producer also says that 'I don't know how to do the scene and Subbu comes up with 4 ways to do so'. Thus the former statement could be a metaphor to describe how difficult the scene was to enact. 
Because rat fighting a tigress that too underwater is quite impossible.

Comment: Thanks Kshitij! You made a really good point, maybe the author just wants to show the difficulty of the task by referring to a weird scene. But the fact that the writer has written the statement of the director in inverted commas maybe means that the director actually said these lines and the scene? Really really thanks though :)

Comment: You're welcome. And I agree with what you said. The director must have said that. The line "Good, but I am not sure it is effective enough" just caught my attention. They might be actually thinking about creating a scene like that (To create an impact on the audience, I suppose). For example, the physics defying action sequences in action films.

Comment: Yes, also, as the scene is of a movie of 1940 or something, I think they might have actually used rat and tigress costumes to create the scene. Maybe the scene is literally what its said by the author.

Comment: Indeed. I would love to watch a scene like that. :)
If you feel my answer is helpful, please mark it as accepted.